# Create a view on multiple row conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have a Cycles table like this:

```
Value   Name    Month

10  P00006  201412
20  P00006  201501
30  P00006  201502
100 P00007  201509
200 P00007  201510
300 P00007  201511
```

I would like to create a view based on this table where for each Name I sum the values of the previous months.
This the expected result :

```
AccruedValue  Name    Month

10  P00006  201412
30  P00006  201501
60  P00006  201502
100 P00007  201509
300 P00007  201510
600 P00007  201511
```

I am not sure this can be achieved without a using a cursor so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test data:

```
create table cycles 
(value NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(250), month VARCHAR2(250));
/
INSERT INTO cycles VALUES(10  , 'P00006','201412');
INSERT INTO cycles VALUES(20  , 'P00006','201501');
INSERT INTO cycles VALUES(30  , 'P00006','201502');
INSERT INTO cycles VALUES(100 , 'P00007','201509');
INSERT INTO cycles VALUES(200 , 'P00007','201510');
INSERT INTO cycles VALUES(300 , 'P00007','201511');
```

View my_view:

```
create or replace view my_view as 
select 
   sum(value) over (partition by name order by month ) as AccruedValue ,
   name ,
   month 
from cycles;
```

Result:

```
select * from v;

10  P00006  201412
30  P00006  201501
60  P00006  201502
100 P00007  201509
300 P00007  201510
600 P00007  201511
```

Comment: the view return exact the same result as you show as   expected result in your question

Comment: Excuse me you are right :). Thank your very much for your help. This topic is closed